# MySQL select difficulties

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

this may be very easy to do but I do not even know how to formulate my problem for search engines (google | stackoverflow).
I am trying to create a HTML form based on data from database.
my problem:
I have table with these columns:

1. id
2. file
3. language
4. etc...

filled with data (example):

```
//no < table > here
//only **file** column is really important for my select (that I am asking for)

id |    file            |  lanugage     | etc
====================================================================
1  |about.php           | english       | something
2  |conta.php           | english       | something
3  |mysql.php           | hungar        | something
4  |mysql.php           | english       | something
5  |mysql.php           | french        | something
6  |blog.php            | french        | something
```

after the select I am asking for array should look like this

```
0 => about.php, 1 => conta.php, 2 => mysql.php, 3 => blog.php
```

**SOLUTION**
I was looking for **distinct** option of SELECT
or 
SELECT t1.file as `Files` from table as t1 group by Files

well this was fast :) thanks

Comment: show us your current PHP/MySQL code, we can't guess it.

Comment: There is none :) I am just trying to "create" select nothing else. IF you like `$query = $this->db->query('SELECT file`

Comment: I agree with @Jocelyn and if you're worried about security, you could always just substitute names/labels (so long as you know the difference).

Comment: So you just want to create a SELECT query that will pull out the "file" column from your table and put all rows into one array?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29 ?

Comment: I am not worried about security at all :), just there is nothing to post, I am seeking for **select**, as I said I do not know how to explain more my issue/problem. Just try to understand from provided (exampled) information I posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to

```
SELECT distinct(file) FROM mytable;
```

and then use

[mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

something like that:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT distinct(file) FROM mytable");
$arr=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $arr[] = $row[0];
}
```

Comment: thank you :) **distinct** is what I was looking for everything else is "obvious".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to get the unique (distinct) values for file from this table?

To do that you would use the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT file from table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.file as `Files` from table as t1 group by Files
```

This query is very simple you should learn to use sql.

Comment: valid answer, isn't distinct easier to use?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$dbc = mysql_connect(SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($dbc, DATABASE);

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT `file` FROM `myTable`";
$result = mysql_query($dbc, $query);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like just want to pull all the values from the 'file' column and have them in one array. Try this:

```
// define your database connection in the
// $SERVER, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD, and $DATABSE variables

$link = mysql_connect($SERVER, $USERNAME, $PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db($link , $DATABASE);

// I don't know what you're table name is, so put it in place of 'myTable'
$sql= "SELECT file FROM `myTable` GROUP BY file";
$result = mysql_query($link, $sql);
```

That will grab only the 'file' column for all rows in the table, then you would need to loop through them to get the results into one array:

```
$files_array = array();
while($result && $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $files_array[] = $row['file'];
}
```

This should output the resulting array you are looking for.